# perl - loop through directory to find file.mdb and execute code if file.ldb not found

Tags: perl

I am a beginner PERL programmer and I have come across a snag that I can't get by. I have been reading and re-reading web posts and Simon Cozens book at perl.org all day, but can't seem to solve the problem.

My intention with the code below is to loop through files in a directory and when the file has a certain string a name to verify that the same file name doesn't exist with a different extension and if it doesn't, to print me the file name (later I will implement a delete of the file, but for now I want to ensure it will work.) Specifically, I am finding .mdb files and after checking there are no associated .ldb's files, deleting the .mdb file.

right now my code returns this:

```
RRED_Database_KHOVIS.ldb
RRED_Database_KHOVIS.mdb
I will kill RRED_Database_KHOVIS.mdb

RRED_Database_mkuttler.mdb
I will kill RRED_Database_mkuttler.mdb

RRED_Database_SBreslow.ldb
RRED_Database_SBreslow.mdb
I will kill RRED_Database_SBreslow.mdb
```

i want it to only return the "I will kill..." after a .mdb file with no associated .ldb file.

My current code is below. I appreciate any help offered...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use diagnostics;

my $dir = "//vfg1msfs01ab/vfgcfs01\$/Regulatory Reporting/Access Database/";
my $filename = "RRED_Database";
my $fullname, my $ext;

opendir DH, $dir or die "Couldn't open the directory: $!";
while ($_ = readdir(DH)) {
my $ext = ".mdb";
if ((/$filename/) && ($_ ne $filename . $ext)) {
    print "$_ \n";
    unless (-e $dir . s/.mdb/.ldb/) {
        s/.ldb/.mdb/;
        print "I will kill $_ \n\n" ;
        #unlink $_ or print "oops, couldn't delete $_: $!\n";
    }
    s/.ldb/.mdb/;
}   
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looping through files, I like to use 'next' statements repeatedly to assure that I'm only looking at exactly what I want.  Try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;
use diagnostics;

my $dir = "//vfg1msfs01ab/vfgcfs01\$/Regulatory Reporting/Access Database/";
my $filename = "RRED_Database";
my $fullname, my $ext;

opendir DH, $dir or die "Couldn't open the directory: $!";
while ($_ = readdir(DH)) {
  my $ext = ".mdb";

  # Jump to next while() iteration unless the file begins 
  # with $filename and ends with $ext, 
  # and capture the basename in $1
  next unless $_ =~ m|($filename.*)$ext|;

  # Jump to next while() iteration if if the file basename.ldb is found
  next if -f $1 . ".ldb";

  # At this point, we have an mdb file with no matching ldb file
  print "$_ \n";
  print "I will kill $_ \n\n" ;
  #unlink $_ or print "oops, couldn't delete $_: $!\n";
}
```

Comment: thanks for this. i found an answer as well - posted below - though your code seems cleaner. I will try yours now...

Comment: in your code I am getting a "use of uninitialized value $1" at the line "next if -f $1 . ".ldb"; ...   i assume the ($filename.*) is how you store the basename to $1 variable, but I don't understand this fully... i will research, but is there something I am missing?

Comment: can't post my answer for 7 more hours! too young on stackoverflow :(

Comment: thanks again for this code, i figured it all out and it basically solves the problem, with a minor adjustment that may not have been clear from my first post... important thing is i learned exactly what your code was doing enough to both know it's a lot leaner and that it wasn't doing exactly what i needed

Answer (score 0):

While stuart's anwser made it more lean... I was able to also get it to work with the code below... (i changed .mdb to .accdb because I am now dealing with different file type)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Spec;
use diagnostics;

my $dir = "//vfg1msfs01ab/vfgcfs01\$/Regulatory Reporting/Access Database/";
my $filename = "RRED_Database";
my $ext;

opendir DH, $dir or die "Couldn't open the directory: $!";
while ($_ = readdir(DH)) {
    my $ext = ".accdb";
    if ((/$filename/)  && ($_ ne $filename . $ext)  && ($_ !~ /.laccdb/)) {
        # if file contains database name, is not the main database and is not a  locked version of db
        s/$ext/.laccdb/;
        unless (-e File::Spec->join($dir,$_)) { 
            s/.laccdb/$ext/;
            #print "I will kill $_ \n\n";
            unlink $_ or print "oops, couldn't delete $_: $!\n";
        }
        s/.laccdb/$ext/;
    }   
}
```